# Receiving "execution expired" errors on Twitter from Heroku

Tags: heroku, twitter

Starting a few days ago, I have been receiving "execution expired" errors from Twitter on Heroku. I don't receive this error in development, but when I deploy to Heroku I get it all the time.

It seems like other people are having this issue as well. See this bug report on the Twitter gem: https://github.com/sferik/twitter/issues/401#issuecomment-21614751

(although I don't think it's actually a bug with the Twitter gem as it seems Heroku-specific...)

Any idea how to solve this issue and why it is happening?

```
Stacktrace (most recent call first):
  Twitter::Error::ClientError: execution expired
  net/http.rb in initialize at line 878
  File "net/http.rb", line 878, in initialize
    TCPSocket.open(conn_address, conn_port, @local_host, @local_port)
  File "net/http.rb", line 878, in open
    TCPSocket.open(conn_address, conn_port, @local_host, @local_port)
  File "net/http.rb", line 878, in block in connect
    TCPSocket.open(conn_address, conn_port, @local_host, @local_port)
  File "net/http.rb", line 877, in connect
    s = Timeout.timeout(@open_timeout, Net::OpenTimeout) {
  File "net/http.rb", line 862, in do_start
    connect
  File "net/http.rb", line 851, in start
    do_start
  File "net/http.rb", line 1367, in request
    start {
  File "new_relic/agent/instrumentation/net.rb", line 33, in request_with_newrelic_trace
    request_without_newrelic_trace( request, *args, &block )
  File "faraday/adapter/net_http.rb", line 75, in perform_request
    http.request create_request(env)
  File "faraday/adapter/net_http.rb", line 38, in call
    http_response = perform_request(http, env)
  File "faraday/response.rb", line 8, in call
    @app.call(env).on_complete do |environment|
  File "faraday/response.rb", line 8, in call
    @app.call(env).on_complete do |environment|
  File "faraday/response.rb", line 8, in call
    @app.call(env).on_complete do |environment|
  File "faraday/request/url_encoded.rb", line 14, in call
    @app.call env
  File "faraday/request/multipart.rb", line 13, in call
    @app.call env
  File "twitter/request/multipart_with_file.rb", line 14, in call
    @app.call(env)
  File "faraday/connection.rb", line 247, in run_request
    self.app.call(env)
  File "faraday/connection.rb", line 112, in post
    run_request(:#{method}, url, body, headers, &block)
  File "twitter/client.rb", line 108, in request
    connection.send(method.to_sym, path, params, &request_setup).env
  File "twitter/client.rb", line 72, in post
    request(:post, path, params, signature_params)
  File "twitter/api/utils.rb", line 51, in objects_from_response
    response = send(request_method.to_sym, path, options)[:body]
  File "twitter/api/users.rb", line 260, in block in users
    objects_from_response(Twitter::User, method, "/1.1/users/lookup.json", merge_users(arguments.options, users))
  File "twitter/core_ext/enumerable.rb", line 5, in block (2 levels) in threaded_map
    Thread.new { yield object }
```

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17817470/twitter-connection-timeout?noredirect=1#comment26066985_17817470

Comment: It appears this is due to Twitter blacklisting Heroku's primary IP addresses. If you are having this issue, please file a ticket with Heroku and comment on this Twitter discussion: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/20185